# How to update dependency of a published package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-publish

I want to install  package `A`. Package `A`  uses package `B` `version:1` as its dependency.

However, package `B` `version:1` deprecated by the author. On installation of package `A` npm warns that package `B` should be updated.

Can I update the package `B` to the latest version on my end?

Comment: How does B define its dependency on A (exact version, ~ or ^)? Would that also be satisfied by the newer version? If not, no you can't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for reply and editing.
Actually I want to install `pdfkit`.
`pdfkit` uses `core-js`.
On installation,  npm warns that `core-js:2.6.11` is deprecated.
So, I want to know that how to solve that.
Can i update the `core-js` dependency of `pdfkit` on my end.

Comment: pdfkit doesn't depend directly on core-js, which makes it more complicated. I guess your dependency is ultimately on `core-js@^2.x.y`, for which 2.6.11 is the latest version.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Correct. Thanks for help